# Delete Profile settings via migration tool?

Tags: profile, migration-tool, ant

I'm trying make changes within a box, and I can see how to change settings via the migration tool, but I'd like to delete all `loginIpRanges` for a certain profile. Is this possible? I attempted deleting them from the `.profile` and doing a `deployUnpackaged` and that didn't work, and I'm not sure how to target those settings with a `destructiveChanges.xml`.